# Preload tables dynamically

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have this query in which I am preloading tables dynamically.

```
 assoc_models = [:example]
          from(
            q in queryable,
            preload: ^assoc_models
          )
```

The result is this:

```
 #Ecto.Query<from j in TestModel.Join, preload: [[:example]]>
```

There can be any number of tables inside assoc_models

There is an extra pair of brackets after preload that I want to remove.

Is there a way to get all items from list and then put it in preload to remove the bracket like this

```
  #Ecto.Query<from j in TestModel.Join, preload: [:example]>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no extra pair of brackets. As you can see, `preloads` and `assocs` are [put together](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v2.2.10/lib/ecto/query/builder/preload.ex#L146) into the same list.

One pair of brackets surrounds this list, another one surrounds your preloads.

Comment: Thanks fro your reply. What I meant is I want this query to be like this. preload: [:example]>. Is there any way getting all the tables from assoc_model and put it inside the preload

Comment: I doubt I understand why would you want to fight a visualization issue, but you might use named models: `assoc_models = [example: :example]`. That way the second pair of brackets won’t be shown in the respective `inspect` _Algebra_.

Answer (score 2):

I'll presume you want to automatically preload all associations for any given schema. The schema module has a `.__schema__/1` function/macro. To get the list of associations like this:

```
iex(15)> OneChat.Schema.Message.__schema__(:associations)
[:user, :channel, :edited_by, :stars, :attachments, :reactions, :mentions]
```

Here is a simple module to auto preload a query, given the schema module.

```
defmodule AutoPreload  do
  def preload(query, schema_module) do
    preloads = schema_module.__schema__(:associations)
    Ecto.Query.preload(query, ^preloads)
  end
end
```

And here it is in action:

```
iex(17)> AutoPreload.preload(from(m in OneChat.Schema.Message), OneChat.Schema.Message)
#Ecto.Query<from m in OneChat.Schema.Message,
 preload: [[:user, :channel, :edited_by, :stars, :attachments, :reactions, :mentions]]>
```